# Network File System mount, with local fallback?

Tags: linux, networking, synchronization, nfs

I'm trying to set up a directory that is stored on a local (Linux) server and mirrored on several (windows) computers.

I've looked at options like [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), but with the type of data being worked on it's very important to have instantaneous sync to the server.

I have also looked at NFS mounting (ie sftp, webdav, etc.), but these clients are taking real-time data and I can't afford any network connectivity problems.

What would be perfect is a combination of the two : NFS mount (and "instantaneous sync") for as long as the network is up, with a local fallback storage location in case there is a network problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using one of the following:

- Block device emulation:

  - [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/)
  - iSCSI + RAID1
- Distributed file systems:

  There are a number of file systems in this segment, with varying semantics and feature sets. I'm naming a few, though I haven't used any of those: GlusterFS, XtreemFS, Lustre.

I remember reading about a mirroring FUSE file system driver that was able to direct read traffic to the fastest (local) mirror using latency profiling. You could see if you can find it again [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems).

Comment: XtreemFS looks very interesting. Unfortunately they don't have a working Windows version yet :( That seems to be my biggest problem, finding something that will work in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Magnesium - they do now http://www.xtreemfs.org/index.php , and Ceph might be interesting too.